# Perl: how to fix SOAP::Lite delcampe-api-client example?

Tags: perl, soap

Here http://code.google.com/p/delcampe-api-client/wiki/Info#Perl is code example of delcampe-api-client in Perl. Obviously, there is an syntax error, running the code i got:

```
syntax error at test.pl line 9, near "-> service"
Bareword "SOAP::Lite" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 8.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

If i change code to little bit more meaningful for me, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::WSDL;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $service = new SOAP::Lite;
print $service
    ->uri('http://api.delcampe.net/soap.php?wsdl')
    ->getServerTime()
    ->result;
```

I got:

```
A service address has not been specified either by using SOAP::Lite->proxy() or a service description)
```

What is wrong with this code? What proxy? Service description?

[ If you think, i have no experience with SOAP, you are certainly right. Still, how to get this little example to work. PHP example worked nicely, but not the Perl's one. ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would give "The Fine Documentation" a try. This should work, however:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Lite;
use SOAP::WSDL;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://api.delcampe.net/soap.php?wsdl');

print $service->getServerTime()->result;
```

**Edit:**

Documentation can be found at http://guide.soaplite.com/ - also perldoc SOAP::Lite from the command line.

The example (above) on the web site appears not to work on more than one count: this one, however, is tested and works on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use SOAP::Lite;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $service = SOAP::Lite->service('http://api.delcampe.net/soap.php?wsdl');

print $service->getServerTime();
```

Comment: Maybe it should, but it does not. You may point me to the documentation what you meant.

Comment: Throwing away SOAP::WSDL from script which is example of dealing with WSDL does not seem a solution ;(

Comment: Did you try it? What error message did you get? Well  the example work on my machine (Linux FC15) without it - which means it is not a dependency for SOAP::Lite v.o.712 (and I do not remember it ever was - but I may be mistaken). In fact, SOAP::WSDL is not even installed on my box. A corsory reading of Lite.pm shows that, in fact, Lite.pm packs a wsdl parser. But note also the missing  ''->result'', which is an error in the original example.

Comment: Sorry, did not try with  SOAP::WSDL too, thought that this was the redundant for you. Yes, i got result now. Thank you!