# Getting "A service address has not been specified..." when using Perl SOAP::Lite to do call using wsdl

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to do a SOAP call to `http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx` using the WSDL.

My code is as follows

```
use SOAP::Lite;

my $client = SOAP::Lite->new;
$client    = $client->service( "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?wsdl" );

my $soapResp = $client->call( "ConvertSpeed", 100, "kilometersPerhour", "milesPerhour" );

if ( $soapResp->fault ) {
    print $soapResp->faultstring;
}
else {
    print $soapResp->result;
}
```

This gives me the following error

> A service address has not been specified either by using SOAP::Lite->proxy() or a service description)

I believe that the WSDL is supposed to provide the service address, but it does not seem to be doing that here.

I have tried setting the service address to `http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx` via `$client->proxy("http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx")` after `$client->service()`, but that just gives me an error saying:

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP header SOAPAction: #ConvertSpeed
```

I assumed the WSDL was supposed to provide the service address and so omitted the `$client->proxy()` bit and tried other stuff.

This ranged from chaining methods differently and eventually chaining as little as possible (the code above) to changing the way the call is made.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9099785/2277482) I tried

```
$client->ConvertSpeed(100, "kilometersPerhour", "milesPerhour")
```

which just seems to return nothing.

This is running on Perl 5.10 and version 0.714 of SOAP::Lite.

I'm not sure what else to try, but I have confirmed that the same SOAP call works from Python(see edit).

EDIT:

```python
from zeep import Client

client = Client('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?wsdl')
result = client.service.ConvertSpeed(100, 'kilometersPerhour', 'milesPerhour')

print(result)
```

Comment: The *service address* is different from the *proxy address*. The WSDL URL that you are using seems to be valid, yet the library is claiming that it doesn't have a service description. If you have working Python code then please edit your question to show it.

Comment: @Borodin see edit in post. That is using python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question to PerlMonks as well since it didn't seem to be doing well here. According to the answer I received [there](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1207459) `SOAP::Lite` isn't ideal for a complex service using the WSDL. Instead everything should be specified using the `uri()` and `proxy()` methods. If the WSDL is to be used then `XML::Compile::WSDL11` is the module to look at.

The answer supplies working code for the call using `SOAP::Lite` without the WSDL as follows :

```
$client = SOAP::Lite->new(
        uri   => 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/',
        proxy => 'http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx',
           );

$client->on_action(sub {"http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertSpeed"});
$client->autotype(0);
$sheader = SOAP::Header->new('');
$sheader->type(xml => '');
$client->ns('http://www.webserviceX.NET/','web');
$client->envprefix('soapenv');

push @request, SOAP::Data->name(speed => 100)->prefix('web');
push @request, SOAP::Data->name(FromUnit => 'kilometersPerhour')->prefix('web');
push @request, SOAP::Data->name(ToUnit => 'milesPerhour')->prefix('web');

$soapResp = $client->ConvertSpeed($sheader,@request);

print $soapResp->result,"\n";
```

If I get a working example using `XML::Compile::WSDL11` I will post it here. As I am unsure if I am going to look into it soon I decided to at least post this since the question is more focused on using a WSDL with `SOAP::Lite`